# How do I classify multiple time series into different buckets?

Tags: time-series, classification, multiple-regression, pca, multicollinearity

I have 60 different time series, denoted $\{y_{i,t}\}_{i=1}^{60}$. So $i$ denotes the time series in question, and $t$ obviously denotes the time period from $t=1$ to $t=T$, where $t \in \mathbb{N}_{+}$. Each time series $i$ is of the same length $T$.

I am trying to classify these 60 time series into buckets (preferably two buckets). However, the time series in question are yields for different maturities (so, empirical finance for those curious), and so $\{y_{i,t}\}_{i=1}^{60}$ are ordered. Hence it is required that there must be a restriction which in effect results in series $i=1$ to $i=x$ being classified into Bucket 1 and the series $i=x+1$ to $i=60$ are classified into Bucket 2. This is important because the time series are ordered. ($i=1$ is one month maturity, $i=2$ is two months maturity, $i=3$ is three months maturity, ... $i=60$ is sixty months maturity.)

So in essence I am looking for a statistical test or algorithm that is data driven and chooses the correct $i=x$ for me. At the moment I have been looking at multivariate correlations and tests of multicollinearity. But again then it results in me having to arbitrarily choose the level of correlation which "breaks" the 60 series into two buckets, as opposed to being purely statistically dependent, if you see what I mean.

Furthermore, I have no a priori view on which criteria should be utilised. My ultimate aim, once I have my two buckets, is to then use Dynamic PCA to effectively obtain two independent variables (by taking, most likely, the first PC from each respective bucket) and then perform PCA regression. So I am open minded with respect to the criteria for separating the different time series into two buckets so long as it is appropriate afterwards for running D-PCA on each bucket.

For reference, some of the time series in question have a very high correlation, by which I'm talking of 0.90 or higher.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide your readers some basis or criterion for classifying these series.  Could you also clarify what you mean by "$x$"? Are you implying these 60 series have an inherent sequence from 1 to 60 and you are looking for a point in this sequence where some property of these series changes dramatically?

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I have edited my original post to make more clear. At least I hope it is more clear now.
1) Yes to your second point, this is because the 60 time series are ordered.
2) Regarding criterion, I a priori have no preference, however the intention once I have separated the 60 time series into two distinct buckets is to take the first Dynamic Principal Component from each bucket, and so I want something that is most appropriate for this.
Thanks!